# Unable to switch between AMD Radeon graphics and Intel HD

Tags: unity, lenovo, intel-graphics, amd-graphics, radeon

I have an old laptop **Lenovo Z51-70** with Ubuntu-20.04 and am trying to switch between AMD graphics (Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X) from Intel using `DRI_PRIME=1` random variable

I get this error when I try to switch the graphics using `xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0`

Output-

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 (RRSetProviderOffloadSink)
  Value in failed request:  0x45
  Serial number of failed request:  16
  Current serial number in output stream:  17
```

Output of `xrandr --listproviders`

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0xd7 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 6 outputs: 0 associated providers: 0 name:VERDE @ pci:0000:04:00.0
```

Graphics details

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
04:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] [1002:6820] (rev 81)
```

I have also tried using `amdgpu` but the output remains the same.

Please help at the earliest.

[Update]

Output of `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

```
adeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: can't create border_color_buffer
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: can't create border_color_buffer
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: can't create border_color_buffer
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: can't create border_color_buffer
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: can't create border_color_buffer
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: can't create border_color_buffer
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: can't create border_color_buffer
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: can't create border_color_buffer
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: can't create border_color_buffer
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: can't create border_color_buffer
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: can't create border_color_buffer
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  68
  Current serial number in output stream:  69
```

Comment: You don't need to use `xrandr`. You can run applications with `DRI_PRIME=1`. For testing check `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` with ``DRI_PRIME=1` and without.

Comment: `DRI_PRIME=1` shows the same error.

I have update the output of `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

Comment: What is the kernel version?

Comment: Currently, it's `5.13.0-41-generic` but I've checked with 5.4, 5.10, and 5.11 as well. The error persists.

Comment: It is a bug. I never had this issue. I suggest reporting it to Launchpad.

Comment: I'm suspecting a hardware issue.. but it was working past 6 months